# How to slow down the movement

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to make the TCanvas move up a little then back down. But with current code it does it so fast you can not see it.  Was hopeing someone could give me the proper way to do this..

```
    {this will give the attack amimation}
procedure TGameData.AnimateAttack(slot: Integer);
begin
   if slot = 1 then
   begin
     fgame.slot1.Top := fgame.slot1.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot1.Repaint;
     fgame.slot1.Top := fgame.slot1.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot1.Repaint;
   end;
   if slot = 2 then
   begin
     fgame.slot2.Top := fgame.slot2.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot2.Repaint;
     fgame.slot2.Top := fgame.slot2.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot2.Repaint;
   end;
   if slot = 3  then
        begin
     fgame.slot3.Top := fgame.slot3.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot3.Repaint;
     fgame.slot3.Top := fgame.slot3.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot3.Repaint;
   end;
   if slot = 4 then
        begin
     fgame.slot4.Top := fgame.slot4.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot4.Repaint;
     fgame.slot4.Top := fgame.slot4.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot4.Repaint;
   end;
   if slot = 5  then
        begin
     fgame.slot5.Top := fgame.slot5.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot5.Repaint;
     fgame.slot5.Top := fgame.slot5.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot5.Repaint;
   end;
   if slot = 6 then
        begin
     fgame.slot6.Top := fgame.slot6.Top - 9;
     fgame.slot6.Repaint;
     fgame.slot6.Top := fgame.slot6.Top + 9;
     fgame.slot6.Repaint;
   end;



end;
```

Comment: You would need to use some sort of delayed adjustment + repaint for this to work. At the moment you simply move the canvas/repaint each time therefore there is no "gradual" movement. See these [examples](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/FMXTimerAnimation_(Delphi)) one using a timer and the others using the built in animation stuff that comes with XE2.

Comment: Use a `TTimer` to update the position. But in general I would not use controls to do your painting. Just draw directly on the canvas.

Comment: i am drawing directly on canvas, i just what the whole canvas to move up and then back down..

Comment: By canvas you mean paintbox? Or what canvas are you drawing on?

Comment: That just looks like the wrong way to solve your problem, whatever your problem is. Surely all that Top shuffling and Repaint calling is wrong.

Comment: how else you move a card if you dont move the top value?

Comment: @GlenMorse you shouldn't need to call `Repaint` after moving a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the current animation frame number and use a timer to do the animation. Like this:

```
FFrameNumber := 0;
FTimer : = TTimer.Create(Self);
FTimer.Interval := Round (1.0 / FrameRate);
FTimer.OnTimer := AnimationHandler;

...

FFrameNumber := 0;
FTimer.Enabled := True;   // start the animation

...

procedure AnimationHandler(Sender : TObject)
begin
FTimer.Enabled := False;
case FFrameNumber of
  0 : // set the canvas position
  1 : // set the canvas position
  2 : // set the canvas position
  ...
end;

Inc(FFrameNumber);   // next frame

if (FFrameNumber < FrameCount) then
  FTimer.Enabled := True;   
end;
```